# Bloomberg Treasuries PX_Last and daily returns

Tags: returns, bloomberg, bond-yields, price, treasuries

I tried to search for this specific question, although I didn’t found a conclusive answer. 
I have a dataset containing the yields of several T-Bills and T-Notes that were downloaded from a Bloomberg Terminal using the function px_last. 
In order to achieve the actual prices of such securities how I should set up the formula?

1. $P=\frac{FV}{\left(1 + \frac{px_{last}}{100}\right)^{\frac{m}{12}}}$
2. $P=FV \times \left(1 - \left(\frac{px_{last}}{100} \right)^{\frac{m}{12}}\right)$

where $m$ are the months up to maturity.

Then if I need to calculate daily returns, I would kindly ask you if it is correct to use a formula:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R =& \left(1+\frac{px_{last}.shift(1)}{100}\right)^{\frac{1}{365}} - 1 \times \frac{\partial P}{\partial px_{last}} \times \frac{px_{last} - px_{last}.shift(1)}{100} \\
&+ 0.5 \times \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial px_{last}^2} \times \left( \frac{px_{last} - px_{last}.shift(1)}{100} \right)^2
\end{aligned}
$$

or simply

$$R=\frac{P_{t+1}-P_t}{P_t}$$

where: 
**$P$** represent the price formula, 
**$px_{last}.shift(1)$** is intended as the yield of the previous day

Thank you in advance,

A

Comment: (1) Bloomberg can give you the price directly, no need for you to calculate. (2) Your formulas don't comply with industry standards for T-bill calculations.

Comment: (3) The formula $R=(P_{t+1}-P_t)/P_t$ is the best way to calculate return. The other is (a) an approximation (b) requires additional complicated calculations to find the two derivatives, Duration and Convexity.